# Is $88888888^8 + 1$ prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

**Background.**

I was looking at Pythagorean primes $p= x^2 + y^2$, then at a subset, Quartan primes, $p= x^4 + y^4$ http://oeis.org/A002645

I wondered if there were primes of the form $p= x^8 + y^8$, but my searches only produced one result $88888888^8 + 1$ https://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php/8.html

To cut a long story short, I put together some code to look for $p= x^8 + y^8$, and produced $(x,y,p)=$

$$(1,1,2)$$
$$(2,1,257)$$
$$(4,1,65537)$$
$$(6,5,2070241)$$
$$(10,3,100006561)$$
$$(12,7,435746497)$$
$$(13,2,815730977)$$
$$(13,8,832507937)$$

With these values, I found these were Octavan primes https://oeis.org/A006686

By my calculation,
$$88888888^8 + 1^8=$$
$$3897443119493995135240117470484161627805761928038551890318852097$$

**My question:** Is this number prime?

Also, nice to know:
Is there an online method to test numbers, of the order $4E+63$, for primality?
Is there a compressive list of prime varieties?

Comment: According to Maxima it is a prime number.

Comment: Maple says that this is a prime number

Comment: you can use https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM

Comment: Thank you! If you want to post as an answer, I'll up vote.

Comment: http://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php (factor up to 60 digits), http://www.numberempire.com/primenumbers.php (prime checking up to 128 digits)

Comment: Also, according to Maple,  $8888888888888888888^8+1$ is prime.

Comment: And so is $9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999^9+2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your number is prime. I verified this first using an implementation of the Miller-Rabin probabilistic prime test, followed by the AKS primality test.

Interestingly, it turns out that WolframAlpha [is capable of verifying that this is prime](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+3897443119493995135240117470484161627805761928038551890318852097+prime) as well.

Comment: Is there some place for a newbie in number theory to read about these probabilistic prime tests?

Comment: @mixedmath Thank you!

Comment: Many elementary number theory texts will include something about probabilistic primality tests. But by far the most common is the Miller-Rabin, and a quick search will lead you to many proofs and examples of its use.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is "just" doing a probable prime test.  Why AKS, and which implementation?  I would love to see one that can prove this number in under 5 minutes (which is still 80000 times slower than ECPP).

Comment: PFGW Version 3.7.10.64BIT.20150809.x86_Dev [GWNUM 28.7]

Primality testing 88888888^8+1 [N-1/N+1, Brillhart-Lehmer-Selfridge]                                    
Running N-1 test using base 3                                                  
Running N-1 test using base 5                                                  
Running N+1 test using discriminant 19, base 3+sqrt(19)                                    
Calling N-1 BLS with factored part 100.00% and helper 2.84% (303.32% proof)     88888888^8+1 is prime! (0.0239s+0.0001s)